# Loading the databases from previous installation

Tags: mysql

My Windows OS crashed today. Now I have recovered all the files in `Program files/MySQL` folder.(I **don't have** the exported `.sql` file)

With the new installation of `MySQL 5.6`(same as before), can I get those databases back(Or how to load the data to new installation of MySQL)? Please suggest.

Comment: Does your set of recovered files include a sub-folder "data"? If yes, you should have pretty good chances.

Comment: Yes. It does. I replaced that with old one. But no luck!

Comment: I think you are in the wrong site. http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is the place to ask that.

Comment: How did you replace it? Simply via drag-and-drop into the MySQL folder of Program Files?

Comment: @HaukeP. Yes. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: @xlembouras Thanks. I shall post this question there.

Comment: Look at this [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files) may b this will help you.

Comment: well I have to ask you some ques:1) which type of tables you were consisting? (InnoDB/MyISAM) etc. 2) what folders did you recover. Did it have ibdata files database folders?

Answer (score 4):

The location of your data files for MySQL on Windows is unfortunately dependent on a few parameters (MySQL version, Windows version, installation directory). The cleanest approach is to find your `my.cnf` file, which is usually located at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server [version]\my.ini`, but might also be at `C:\Windows\my.ini` if you used a custom installation directory. In this file, look for the `datadir` setting to find your data files. You can follow the same procedure for your new installation to figure out where to copy those files to.

References:

[MySQL Installation Layout on Microsoft Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-installation-layout.html)

[Troubleshooting a Microsoft Windows MySQL Server Installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-troubleshooting.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try copying the contents of your recovered data folder into a new folder here:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\MySQL\data
```

Then try starting the MySQL demon and check if you can access your data again.

Comment: No. It doesn't. In my new installation, `VirtualStore`  folder only has `Windows` folder as its child. I created `\Program Files\MySQL\data` manually and copied data. Restarted mysql. Still not working.

Comment: Have you checked the log files if MySQL tries to read the data? Could you add any seemingly relevant information from the log files to your initial question?

Answer (score 3):

According to this: [Copying MySQL Databases to Another Machine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html).

> You can copy the **.frm**, **.MYI**, and **.MYD** files for MyISAM tables between different architectures that support the same floating-point format.
>
> In cases where you need to transfer databases between different architectures, you can use **[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html)** to create a file containing SQL statements. You can then transfer the file to the other machine and feed it as input to the **[mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql.html)** client.

You already copied the data so, I suspect you have installed a Windows with a different architecture to the previous one.

Some ideas:

- Check if your new windows is the same version the previous one.
- Install a virtual machine with the previous one windows version and then use  **[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html)**.

And the most extreme:

- Reinstall you system with the previous version.

Comment: only one problem if he had 64 bit installed and now installed 32 bit you can even VM a 64 Bit OS...